# Intersect maps in Rstudio similar to what is done in QuantumGIS

Tags: qgis, r, intersection

I want to make the intersection of two shapefiles in Rstudio as I usually do in QuantumGIS (due to the intersection function that belongs to the vector tools of this software)

I tried to use the left join tools, but in the table of attributes of these shapefiles there is no field in common to make the intersection.

I can do this for QGIS, but I would like to do it for Rstudio, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean? I use the st_intersection() function from the sf package.

```
install.packages("sf")    
library(sf)
roads = read_sf("roads.shp")
reserve = read_sf("Har_Hanegev/NPA/reserves_south.shp")
roads_reserve = st_intersection(roads, reserve)

# A simple plot to demonstrate
plot(reserve$geometry, col = "lightgreen")
plot(roads$geometry, col = "brown", add = TRUE)
plot(roads_reserve$geometry, col = "blue", add = TRUE, lwd = 4)
```

BTW, I added the tag "R" to the question.

[image]